Ищу паттерн для отправки данных
UPD: Попробовал переформулировать, так как 2 голоса для "закрыть"
Подскажите паттерн для подобного.
Записать необходимо в 2 разные таблицы или вообще в 2 разные базы данных. Если запись не произошла во втором условии, то и откатить всё назад и вернуть ошибку.
Либо записывает всё, либо ничего.
public async Task SendAsync(IDefinerResult definerResult) 
{
    if (definerResult.DefinedLinks.Count != 0)
    {
        await definedLinkDAL.InsertAsync(definerResult.DefinedLinks);
    }

    if (definerResult.NotDefinedLinks.Count != 0)
    {
        await notDefinedLinkDAL.InsertAsync(definerResult.NotDefinedLinks);
    }
}


Это называется "транзакция". Оберните оба действия в одну транзакцию. Тогда они либо оба выполнятся, либо оба не выполнятся. Конкретика реализации зависит от используемой БД и фреймворка, через который вы с БД работаете. Если, конечно, у вас работа с БД, хотя названия методов InsertAsync по идее должны это подразумевать.

@CrazyElf спасибо! Да, про транзакции знаю и наверно в итоге они и нужны. Я думал над чем то подобным транзакциям до БД)

Без БД сложно будет, вам придётся придумывать механизм отката записи, а это очень нетривиальное дело. А представьте, если у вас возникнет проблема в момент отката, что будете делать? Проще поручить транзакции БД, это её специализация. Там всё давно продумано и работает как нужно.

@CrazyElf да, у меня мысленно и возникли эти проблемы что вы описываете про механиз отката и т.д. И это куда сложнее чем готовая транзакция, просто придётся новый ...DAL плодить под этот Result, я думал может как то обойти, но нет)

Судя по названиям, это два разных ресурса? Тогда простой транзакцией не обойтись. Solving the Dual-Write Problem: Effective Strategies for Atomic Updates Across Systems

@AlexanderPetrov 2 разные таблицы в базе.

Хотя смотря как вы там с БД работаете. Но обычно можно объявить транзакцию заранее и передать её в оба записывающие метода. Либо написать один метод, который и туда и туда будет писать. Если у вас в каждом методе отдельный UnitOfWork, то не получится, нужно будет так переделать, чтобы оба метода могли составить вместе один UnitOfWork.

@CrazyElf Хм. действительно заранее же можно... блин) Спасибо!

@AlexanderPetrov спасибо за статью.

В общем, используйте транзакции БД. Это самое простое, что можно сделать. Транзакции в БД разрабатывают много лет, там это продуманный механизм. Если обернуть оба действия в транзакцию, то будет гарантирована атомарность и цельность: либо оба действия будут выполнены, либо оба не выполнены. Состояние, когда выполнено только одно действие, а второе нет, не сможет возникнуть.
Если вы будете реализовать механизм транзакций самостоятельно в своём коде, это потребует много усилий, добиться атомарности и цельности не так то просто.
Подробнее примеры кода работы с транзакциями можно посмотреть по ссылке, которую я выше привёл. И обязательно прочтите там раздел про асинхронность, в частности насчёт этого параметра:
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))

P.S. "В две разных БД" будет немного сложнее. По идее, вам нужно будет открывать отдельно транзакции в каждой из БД и в случае проблем одновременно откатывать их. Но в теории может возникнуть ситуация, когда вы закоммитили одну транзакцию, после чего у вас отвалилась связь и вы остались с одной закоммиченной транзакцией и со второй автоматически откаченной.
Есть ещё конечно DbLink-и, но их очень не любят на промышленных серверах и я не уверен, то можно в одну транзакцию поместить запросы к локальной БД и базе, подключенной через линк. Да и не очень это надёжно тоже.
В общем, лучше, когда в рамках одной БД вся работа происходит.

Задача с распределенными базами сложна потому что возможны проблемы с сетью, ошибки валидации. Собственно появляется потребность как то гарантировать целостность распределенных данных. И появляются паттерны как:
Two-phase commit/XA,
SAGA,
TCC (Try, Confirm, Cancel),
Local Messaging
...
